# wix copy file error

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I get this error:

> Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:SQLSERVERDATAPATH' in
>   section 'Product:*

```
<Property Id="SQLSERVERINSTANCENAME" >
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlServerInstanceName" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Name="MSSQLSERVER" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<Property Id="SQLSERVERDATAPATH" >
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlServerDataPath" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQLSERVERINSTANCENAME]\Setup" Name="SQLDataRoot" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<DirectoryRef Id="SomeFolder">
      <Component Id="MDFFileCopyComponent" Guid="4A002555-D939-4DC9-8C23-62747C2BA905">
        <!--<RemoveFile Id="DatabaseFileRemove" Name="MyFile" On="install" Directory="MyCopyDir" />-->
        <CopyFile Id="MDFFileCopy" FileId="MDF" DestinationDirectory="SQLSERVERDATAPATH" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="LDFFileCopyComponent" Guid="4A002555-D939-4DC9-8C23-62747C2BA905">
        <!--<RemoveFile Id="DatabaseFileRemove" Name="MyFile" On="install" Directory="MyCopyDir" />-->
        <CopyFile Id="LDFFileCopy" FileId="LDF" DestinationDirectory="SQLSERVERDATAPATH" />
      </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

---

updated:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="SomeFolder">
  <Component Id="cmpMDF" Guid="066AFD32-D9B4-42A9-AEE1-F1951DAE959F">
    <File Id="MDF" Name="Database.MDF" Source="DatabaseScripts/Database/Database.MDF" KeyPath="yes" ReadOnly="no">
      <CopyFile Id="MDFFileCopy" DestinationProperty="SQLSERVERDATAPATH" />
    </File>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="cmpLDF" Guid="311283B0-A6E8-402D-BB33-D1BEB6EA282B">
    <File Id="LDF" Name="Database.LDF" Source="DatabaseScripts/Database/Database.LDF" KeyPath="yes" ReadOnly="no">
      <CopyFile Id="LDFFileCopy" DestinationProperty="SQLSERVERDATAPATH" />
    </File>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

---

Log:

MSI (s) (18:BC) [13:42:32:002]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=Database.MDF,SourceCabKey=MDF,DestName=Database.MDF,Attributes=512,FileSize=1178468352,PerTick=32768,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=58982400,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=-67171634,HashPart2=622189464,HashPart3=-328220288,HashPart4=-1777642375,,)

MSI (s) (18:BC) [13:42:32:006]: File: C:\Program Files\MyApp\Database\Database.MDF; To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file

MSI (s) (18:BC) [13:42:32:009]: Source for file 'MDF' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: Database.MDF,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MyApp\Database\,  Size: 1178468352

MSI (s) (18:BC) [13:42:32:015]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Program Files\MyApp\Database\Database.MDF

MSI (s) (18:BC) [13:42:32:034]: Note: 1: 2360

Answer (score 0):

In your `<CopyFile>` you include `DestinationDirectory="SQLSERVERDATAPATH"`
That means you must also have a `<Directory>` with `id="SQLSERVERDATAPATH"` somewhere.

Edit: Looks like you want to use `DestinationProperty="SQLSERVERDATAPATH"` instead.
See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm

Comment: I changed it to DestinationProperty, now it compiles but it doesn't copy the file to the destination folder.

Comment: I updated my post. I moved the <CopyFile> inside <File/> element, still the same.

Comment: Create a logfile while installing; `msiexec /i "your.msi" /l*v "C:\temp\install.log"`, and check that for errors

Comment: the log doesn't show anything went wrong. I updated my post with the log to make it more legible.

Comment: I'm finding that CopyFile works on Windows 7 but nothing is copied on Windows XP. See this feature request: http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/feature-requests/684/